# Need solution regarding imacros !DATASOURCE_LINE issue

Tags: csv, macros, imacros

I have a csv file containing info for tv-series and each tv-series has its own macro. I can get all info without any problems using `{{!COL1}}` etc.
But I need some help on the scenario below.
tv-series.csv

```
Game of Thrones, 2011, Season 2
The Walking Dead, 2015, Season 5
etc.
```

If I want to get the title of a tv-series I will simply use `{{!COL1}}`, and for year `{{!COL2}}`
But I sometimes add new tv-series and the order of them compeletly changes in csv file. Then I have to modify all line #s in all macros manually.
Is there a way to determine the line number based on the firt column (e.g. Game of Thrones)? The info will not change, just the line numbers of them will change. Sorry for my terrible English, I hope I could tell my problem and need some advice.

My code so far

```
VERSION BUILD=8910303 RECORDER=FX
TAB T=1
SET !DATASOURCE tv-series.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 2 => This # should change based on first column

TAG POS=1 TYPE=TEXTFIELD FORM=NAME:title ATTR=ID:titlebox CONTENT={{!COL1}}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the command 'EVAL' and 'switch'-clause. As an example:

```
...
SET !DATASOURCE tv-series.csv
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE 1
SET lineNumber EVAL("switch ('{{!COL1}}') {case 'Game of Thrones': s = 2; break; case 'Something Else': s = 5; break;  /* etc. */}")
SET !DATASOURCE_LINE {{lineNumber}}
...
```

Comment: Interesting solution but does not give me what I want. It looks to me like this 'EVAL()' Statement will pretend that 'Game of Thrones' will always be on Row2, which will become not True anymore if you add some other Row(s) before, the 'Game of Thrones' will then be on Row3/4/5/etc...

Comment: So, do you want to determine the line number of the given title (for example, “Game of Thrones”)?

Comment: Yes, sir, I have a macro for Game of Thrones and it pulls data from a certain row. When I add a new tv-series or remove one or change their order, the line number in macro will be wrong. Then I will have to modify the line number in each macro.

Comment: This problem is solved with the help of JavaScript Scripting Interface. Contact me via e-mail ( shugarjs@gmail.com ) and I’ll give you js-script which reads the entire csv-file “tv-series” and determines the line number of “Game of Thrones”.